# Kivy dropdown isn't showing

Tags: python, kivy

I am making a "SelectBox" widget in kivy similar to the HTML ones. I want to be able to define it like this in kvlang :

`(test.kv)`

```
#:import SelectBox widgets

GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    Button:
        text: "hello"
        size_hint_x: None
        size_hint_y: None
    SelectBox:
        id: appeui
        size_hint_x: None
        size_hint_y: None
        width: root.width - 100
        height: '32dp'
        label: "Select an application"
        SelectOption:
            label: 'Option 1'
            value: '1'
        SelectOption:
            label: 'Option 2'
            value: '2'
        SelectOption:
            label: 'Option 3'
            value: '3'
    Button:
        text: "hello2"
        size_hint_x: None
        size_hint_y: None
    Widget:
        size_hint_x: None
```

I have made the widget like below, but for some reason when I click the button, nothing appears. The `openDropDown` does get called, and the `DropDown` does seem to have child widgets, but they don't show up.

`(widgets.py)`

```
from kivy.event import EventDispatcher
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout


class SelectOption(Label):
    value = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self,
                 *args,
                 **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.background_color = Color(rgba=(1, 1, 1, 1))
        self.bind(on_touch_down=self.select)
        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(self.background_color)
            Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)

    def select(self, *args):
        self.parent.select(self.value)


class SelectBox(StackLayout, EventDispatcher):
    label = StringProperty('Select an option')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.dropdown = DropDown()
        self.value = None
        self.button = Button(text=self.label)
        self.button.id = 'dropdown_label'
        self.add_widget(self.button)
        self.button.bind(on_release=self.openDropDown)
        self.dropdown.bind(on_select=self.set_value)

    def on_label(self, instance, value):
        self.button.text = value

    def add_widget(self, child):
        if isinstance(child, SelectOption):
            self.dropdown.add_widget(child)
        else:
            super().add_widget(child)

    def openDropDown(self, *args):
        self.dropdown.open(self)

    def set_value(self, instance, value):
        self.ids.dropdown_label.text = value
```

This would be the app:
`(TestApp.py)`

```
from kivy.app import App


class TestApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnAnderson Ok, the code in there was 99% of a reproducible example, but I added the extra code to have a full example with a layout.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the height of the `SelectOption`s. They needed to have `size_hint_y` set to None and a fixed height set.

Once I changed them to

```
class SelectOption(Label):
    value = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.size_hint_y = None
        self.height = '32dp'
```

it worked.